Using 'this' in custom Phaser classes
I'm working on an old school RPG using Phaser.js. I have what I know is a simple question. In my custom classes almost all have:
export default class Chest extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite{
  constructor(scene, x, y, name, description) {
        super(scene, x, y, 'treasure');
        this.scene = scene;

Should I be using this.scene or omit it and just use scene? I'm certai  there's a difference, but I don't know what the pros/cons are of each.

You can use scene only in the constructor. Not in other methods, if they need it. To share data with the methods, you need 1. that data to exist on the instance 2. to access it via this. If the parent here also exposes scene through this (which it might, dunno - not into Phaser but scene is passed into super) there is little need to overwrite it yourself if you still need it in other methods.

The comment of @VLAZ is the answer. Just to add using this.scene or scene (as long it is the same object), doesn't matter for the code/runtime (since it is the same object), only for your code-guidelines and generell code readability.

If you look in the documentation, it seems that scene is already a property of Sprite.  If  that is the case, you should always be able to use this.scene without setting it yourself manually. https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite.html
